# How do I escape text in autoconf/m4?

Tags: bash, autoconf, m4

The following code from my configuration.ac file does not work (note the nested square brackets with **[default=no]**):

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(debug,
    [  --enable-debug          build with debugging support [default=no].],
    [DEBUG="$enableval"],
    [DEBUG="no"]
)
```

How can I escape those brackets?

Comment: I don't see any Bash. Why the tag?

Comment: Autoconf scripts are parsed first by m4 and then by the bourne shell.

Answer (score 24):

Found it!  From [this](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/%7Eer258/code/autoconf/index.html) tutorial:

> M4 arguments are quoted with [ and ]. There is NO WAY to escape these, however, you have several options if you wish to insert ['s or ]'s:
>
> 1. Use a [`Quadrigraph'](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Quadrigraphs.html#Quadrigraphs). @<:@ gives you [ and @:>@ gives you ].
> 2. Balance your quotes. M4 will turn [[]] in to []. Beware of using this in arguments to macros. Sometimes, you need to double quote as well ([[[]]]).
> 3. Change the quoting using: changequote(<<,>>) to change the quoting to << and >>. The autoconf documentation (rightly, in my opinion) [warns against](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Changequote-is-Evil.html) the (over) use of this, since it can lead to unexpected results.
> 4. Avoid [ and ] where ever possible. This is my personal choice.

My new code is therefore:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(debug,
    AS_HELP_STRING(
        [--enable-debug],
        [build with debugging symbols @<:@default=no@:>@]),
    [enable_debug="$enableval"],
    [enable_debug="no"]
)
```

Comment: You should set your own answer as THE answer then.

Comment: Autotools absolutely sucks.

Comment: The quoted tutorial has a new [home](https://github.com/edrosten/autoconf_tutorial#hello-world).

Answer (score 9):

`Brackets` are kind of escape characters, so as you do for `'\'`, you may escape brackets `[]` with brackets, eg :

> AC_ARG_ENABLE(debug,
>       [  --enable-debug          build with debugging support **[**[default=no]**]**.],
>       [DEBUG="$enableval"],
>       [DEBUG="no"]
>       )

Note: **[**[ ]default=no[ ]**]** may not work as you expect as m4 should search the end_bracket from the end. It should so be expanded to `[ ]default=no[ ]`.

Comment: Better to use the 'quadrigraph' escapes, @<:@ and @>:@.

Answer (score -1):

use AC_HELP_STRING

Comment: Thanks (that is definitely cleaner) but still the same problem.  In <<AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-debug],[build with debugging support [default=no].])>> the "[" and "]" are missing from output.

Comment: Why the insistence on square brackets in the output?  Use parentheses; it makes your life easier.

Comment: For consistency's sake, because other packages I'm using have square brackets in their output :(

Comment: `AC_HELP_STRING` been deprecated about half a decade ago. Use `AS_HELP_STRING`.